# vbscript to save sync issues folder emails to a folder

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Background:

I am a sysadmin for several Windows 7 machines.  We have switched from an on-premises Exchange server to Office 365 Exchange Online.  The computers are using Outlook 2013/2010 to connect to Exchange Online.  All the clients are using full cache mode, so there is a complete OST cache file on each computer.

Because of this, there are now the following folders showing in the Folder view of Outlook: Sync Issues, then (subfolders) Conflicts, Local Failures and Server Failures.

I could not find a way to remotely administer or view these messages, so my only option appears to be manually opening each user's Outlook and viewing the folders.  I have tried setting up rules to forward any messages that appear in these folders to me, but I could not get them to work on new emails that appear in these folders.

I would like to write a script that will save the email messages in these folders to a network folder where I can view them later.  I would also like to have the script run on an input text file of all the computer names on the network, if possible.

I have no script writing background or knowledge.  This is what I have pieced together from the web so far:

```
Dim OL, NmeSpace  
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set NmeSpace = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set Inbx = NmeSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSyncIssues) 
Set Fldr = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 
DirName = "C:\Emails\" 
For Each itm In Fldr.Items 
    ' Save email as a file. 
Next
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer. I am studying scripting but I do not have the knowledge yet to write the script I want.

Comment: This question looks more appropriate for Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would go about doing that with a vbscript.  Right now it only does the oSyncFolder as I left out the other two folders so you could get some practice writing it yourself.

```
Dim oApp 
Dim ns 
Dim oSyncFolder
Dim oConflictFolder
Dim oSrvFailuresFolder
Dim dirName
dirName = "PathToFolder\"

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set oSyncFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(20)'olFolderSyncIssues
Set oConflictFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(19)'olFolderConflicts
Set oSrvFailuresFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(22)'olFolderServerFailures

Dim iCounter
iCounter = oSyncFolder.Items.Count

    For iCounter = oSyncFolder.Items.Count To 0 Step -1
    Dim oItem
    Set oItem = oSyncFolder.Items.Item(iCounter)
        oItem.SaveAs dirName & "email" & CStr(iCounter) & ".msg"
        'uncomment line below to remove the item after it has been relocated.
        'oItem.Delete
    Next
Set oSyncFolder = Nothing
Set oConflictFolder = Nothing
Set oSrvFailuresFolder = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing



msgbox "Finished"
```

Comment: Thank YOU so much!  I'm going to get started testing this out and learning from it right away.

Comment: Thanks, Sorceri.  I was getting an error about index/array out of bounds when I ran it initially, but I just changed the value from 0 to 1 in "For iCounter..." line and the script completed without error.

Comment: Also, I found that the folder ID for the Local Failures folder is 21 and added the appropriate lines in the variables and binding sections.